# Python - How can I find if an item exists in multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I've tried a few approaches, none of which seem to work for me.

```
board = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

if not 0 in board:
     # the board is "full"
```

I then tried:

```
if not 0 in board[0] or not 0 in board[1]:
    # the board is "full"
```

None of these approaches worked, though the second one generally let the array fill up more. (I wrote code to fill up the array randomly).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: The `# the board is full` was (for lack of a better word) run at the wrong time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to iterate over all the indices of your list to see if an element is a value in one of the nested lists. You can simply iterate over the inner lists and check for the presence of your element, e.g.:

```
if not any(0 in x for x in board):
    pass  # the board is full
```

Using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will serve as a short-stop whenever it encounters an element with a `0` in it so you don't need to iterate over the rest.

Comment: why use `1` and put a condition in your generator expression? Just put the condition as the value:  `any(0 in x for x in board)`

Answer (score 3):

I will try to address what you did wrong:

`if not 0 in board[0] or not 0 in board[1]:` this is almost right - but you should use `and` because to be considered full, both boards must not have 0 at the same time.

Some options:

```
if not 0 in board[0] and not 0 in board[1]: # would work

if 0 not in board[0] and 0 not in board[1]: # more idiomatic

if not(0 in board[0] or 0 in board[1]): # put "not" in evidence, reverse logic

if not any(0 in b for b in board): # any number of boards
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use tool outside the standard library `numpy` is the best way to work with multidimensional arrays by a long way.

```
board = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
board = np.array(board)
print(0 in board)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I would like to keep my program as lightweight as possible. Are there any *major* advantages to using numpy as opposed to some of the other single lines others have proposed?

Comment: It really depends on what operations you're using, but I'd say in general you get a speed up with `numpy` compared to using a loop in python. Also the syntax is super flexible for indexing, i.e. returning the `i`'th row would be `board[:, i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another try with `chain` from `itertools` (that way it works with multiple rows):

```
from itertools import chain

board = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

def find_in_2d_array(arr, value):
    return value in chain.from_iterable(arr)

print(find_in_2d_array(board, 0))
print(find_in_2d_array(board, 1))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```