# Find word in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I´m new into python, so I apreciate any help.
I´m trying to develope a code that can search for a specific word in a csv file, but I don´t why he doesn´t recognize a word that I know it is in the program. I'm always getting "Não encontrei".

My code:

```
#Definir perfis

def pilar():
    pilar = input("Perfil do pilar:")
    csv_file=csv.reader(open(r"C:\Users\tomas\Documents\ISEP\5º Ano\TESE\PROGRAMA\PERFIS.csv"))
    
    for row in csv_file:
        if pilar in csv_file:
            print("Pilar: ", pilar)
        else:
            print("Não encontrei")
pilar()
```

Comment: which specific word do you want to detect and please upload the csv file using google drive link or post a format of the dataset.

Comment: Hi there. the word can be "IPE 100" or "IPE 120"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
search_list = []
if any(pilar in x for x in board):
    print("Pilar: ", pilar)
else: print("Não encontrei")
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this way, but what I get is "Não encontrei" for every line of the csv file.

Comment: Hey @<Tomás de Alneida>, I've update my answer, can you have a look

Comment: hello @<Quan Huynh>, and thanks for your time! Can you please check if the code should look like this?

Comment: First thing first, you should format you code a bit. Second, I've find a beeter way from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369718/python-how-can-i-find-if-an-item-exists-in-multidimensional-array). Check my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
def pilar():
    pilar = input("Perfil do pilar:")
    csv_file=csv.reader(open(r"C:\Users\tomas\Documents\ISEP\5º Ano\TESE\PROGRAMA\PERFIS.csv"))
    search_list = []
    for row in csv_file:
        if pilar in csv_file:
            search_list.append(pilar)
        else:
            print("Não encontrei")
pilar()
```